# Caching 401 response on bad token in nginx njs

Tags: nginx, cache, http-caching

In our application whenever a token (that arrives in a header) is invalid - it is practically guaranteed there won't be an exact valid token.
So I'm trying to offload the responsibility of responsding 401 to nginx (with or without njs)
Trying to avoid maintaining a service with a cache that is being hammered by invalid requests.

I was thinking to js_content each call and check in a local "in memory cache" of the invalid token or even better to have an API to nginx cache but I can't seem to find documentation on any of the above.

Auth request doesn't seem helpful since I won't have a way populating the cache with a 401 that will be returned from my service (in a "cache miss")

Any other possible way will be welcomed but I would like to acheive the ability to offload this to nginx

Comment: `proxy_cache_valid 401 404 60m` maybe is that what you look for

Comment: interesting, but can I cache based on a header and not a URL?

Comment: this cache for 404 and 401 header, or what exactly header you mean?

Comment: The API token is in a specific header